# Deleting Windows.old when disk cleanup fails

Tags: windows-7, usb, boot

I have an old Windows installation file, `Windows.old` and I want to get rid of it. I have tried to get ownership of it, didn't help. Have tried disk cleanup, again this didn't help. Disk cleanup just crashes. Now I want to create a lightweight startup disk on my USB drive and delete the folder. I have installed FreeDOS but could not access my C: disk via FreeDOS to delete the files. Please tell me how I can do that via FreeDOS or suggest another fast way of creating an OS on USB drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using FreeDOS, you can use something like Ubuntus live disk, which will able you to run Ubuntu Linux in memory and not add/change anything on your disks.

Ubuntu can be downloaded from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Note that you might have to spend some time getting the Windows partition mounted, but as soon as that partition is mounted you will have complete access to the files on that partition. Be aware that if you delete to much, you can potentially destroy the Windows installation, rendering you unable to boot up Windows again. So be carefull when doing this.